# Is there an official documentation of available transitions between activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

Can't find any official documentation about available transitions between activities supported by the operating system.

I can find only custom xml transitions generated by the community in google but not official supported transitions given by the OS.

Any help with this will be grated...

Maybe does not exist any transition given by the OS and all of them must be customly generated by the developer?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html did you see this? "Start an activity with a shared element" may things that you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the offical documentation for Transition Animations
https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html

---

[AutoTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/AutoTransition.html) - Default transition. Fade out, move and resize, and fade in views, in that order.

[Fade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Fade.html) - `fade_in` fades in views
`fade_out` fades out views
`fade_in_out` (default) does a `fade_out` followed by a `fade_in`.

[ChangeBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/ChangeBounds.html) - Moves and resizes views.